# Problems importing GDK

Tags: python, user-interface, import, gtk, gdk

I am trying to import GDK to my program however I continue to get an error

```
No module named GDK
```

Do you know how I can fix this? Since it was working before I already tried `import gtk.GDK`
and `import GDK`.

I have installed PyGTK and PyGDK is part of of it pyGTK.

Comment: Well, obvious first question: have you installed it? And what platform are we talking about?

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
import gtk.gdk
```

(note: small letters)