# Problems with PyGTK's "gdk" module

Tags: python, gtk, irc

The `gtk` module for Python does some weird magic in order to import a
module named `gdk`.  There is no actual `gdk` module anywhere.  The
beginning of the `gtk/__init__.py` module looks like this:

```
# load the required modules:
import gobject as _gobject

ver = getattr(_gobject, 'pygobject_version', ())
if ver < (2, 11, 1):
    raise ImportError(
        "PyGTK requires PyGObject 2.11.1 or higher, but %s was found" % (ver,))

if 'gtk._gtk' in sys.modules:
    _gtk = sys.modules['gtk._gtk']
else:
    from gtk import _gtk

import gdk
```

Apparently `gdk`, like [Athena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athena), springs forth fully formed from the
`_gtk.so` shared library included in the `gtk` module.  That's all
well and good, but the problem I'm trying to get handle on is that
using [weechat](http://www.weechat.org/), loading a Python script that uses `gtk` works the
first time, but subsequently fails with a traceback like this:

```
python: loading script "/home/username/.weechat/python/lnotify.py"
python: stdout/stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
python: stdout/stderr:   File "/home/username/.weechat/python/lnotify.py", line 20, in <module>
python: stdout/stderr:     import weechat, string, pynotify
python: stdout/stderr:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/pynotify/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
python: stdout/stderr:     import gtk
python: stdout/stderr:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
python: stdout/stderr:     import gdk
python: stdout/stderr: ImportError: No module named gdk
python: unable to parse file "/home/username/.weechat/python/lnotify.py"
```

So, something is happening such that suddently the `gtk` module
becomes unable to find the `gdk` module in the shared library.  I'm
not even sure where to start diagnosing this further, because I'm not
entirely sure what could cause this sort of symbol resolution problem.

Have you seen anything like this before?

Comment: Couple of questions a) can you use introspection via `gi.repository` instead of `pygtk`? Can you reproduce this in a realm without `weechat` (i.e. make sure all imports are reset before importing)? Unfortunately I can not help beyond that.. did you try to `import gtk.gdk` as suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923746/problems-importing-gdk

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from the fact that each C extension module is loaded only once per process, whereas WeeChat uses multiple interpreter instances within that single process context, one per script.  This [does not play well](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#bugs-and-caveats) with extension modules [for a number of reasons](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Multiple_Python_Sub_Interpreters).

In this particular case, module initialization is run only once upon the first import of the extension module `gtk._gtk`, which is, as you have noted, where `gtk.gdk` springs into existence.  From that point on, every attempt to `import gtk` will find that `_gtk` has already been loaded and thus duplicate a shallow copy of its module dictionary within the new interpreter context.  This will get you access to `gtk._gtk`, but the extension initialization function is not called again, which is why subsequent interpreters will wind up missing `gtk.gdk`.

You can reproduce this behaviour without WeeChat or using sub-interpreters by importing `gtk`, deleting references from `sys.modules` and importing `gtk` again:

```
import sys
import gtk
for mod in sys.modules.keys():
    if mod.startswith('gtk'):
        sys.modules.pop(mod)
import gtk
# throws "ImportError: No module named gdk"
```

There is no easy way around this.  You could try and

1. fix PyGTK to use an initialization procedure that is compatible with (re)loading it in a different interpreter context
2. `fork()` for each script executed in WeeChat to provide real isolation (but what to do on Windows?) and avoid this problem at the cost of additional overhead.